# int input from lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to qt I want to make a calculator but for that I had to take in numbers from user in `QLineEdit` but it gives input in string so how can I use lineedit to take input from user or I should use textbox for that.Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **QString** (which you are getting from the input field) has a method which does that, it is `toInt()`

Example:

```
QString num="123";
int n = num.toInt();
```

Edit:
here is the vise-verca if you need it:

```
int num = 123;
QString str= QString::number(num);
```

Comment: Can it works if user enters input like 123+455 if yes what would be the result?

Comment: You can give it a try, though my guess is that it will not work. You will have to parse the input into two numbers and recognize their function ( multiplication, addition and the likes) and then perform it. When I was learning Qt I also did a calculator, where you inputed the numbers in 2 fields and chose the function by clicking a button. If you redesign the interface to something similar it will be much easier to parse the input.

Comment: @Bloodcount There's nothing to guess, integer parsing is not an expression evaluator :) It won't work if you pass "123+455".

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way to assure that user inputs only numbers is to use `QSpinBox` for sure.

On the other hand if you'd like to stick with `QLineEdit` you may want to use `QIntValidator` and `setValidator` method of `QLineEdit` to allow only integer input.